# Unable to start rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I am unable to start rabbitmq on Debian 6

it just wont show any error. but wont start..I found the log files.

```
...

starting database                                                     ...BOOT ERROR: FAILED
Reason: {error,{future_upgrades_found,[exchange_event_serial,
                                       semi_durable_route,trace_exchanges]}}
Stacktrace: [{rabbit_upgrade,'-maybe_upgrade/0-fun-0-',2},
             {rabbit_upgrade,with_upgrade_graph,1},
             {rabbit_mnesia,init_db,2},
             {rabbit_mnesia,init,0},
             {rabbit,'-run_boot_step/1-lc$^1/1-1-',1},
             {rabbit,run_boot_step,1},
             {rabbit,'-start/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1},
             {rabbit,start,2}]
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{rabbit,failure_during_boot}}}}}"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message is right there in what you pasted: "error,{***future_upgrades_found***".

Typically this is because you upgraded the version of RabbitMQ on your system and then (a) subsequently downgraded but didn't blow away the database, or (b) tried to run an older version of RabbitMQ against the upgraded database.

Re-Create your database (or upgrade to the appropraite version of RabbitMQ that the DB was created with) and the problem will go away.